# Manipulate data in a QAbstractListModel from a QML ListView

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt4, qt4.8

I have a QML ListView which uses a QAbstractListModel subclass as a model.

```
ListView {
    id: myListView
    x: 208
    y: 19
    width: 110
    height: 160
    delegate: myListDelegate {}
    model: MyListModel
    opacity: 0
}
```

The model is a list of `MyListItem`s.

```
class MyListModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum MyRoles {
        HeadingRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        DescriptionRole,
        QuantityRole
    };

    explicit MyListModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    void addMyListItem(const MyListItem &item);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    void dropList();

private:
    QList<MyListItem> m_list;

};
```

In the delegate I have a mousearea.

How I can intercept a click on the mousearea and pick **that** `MyListItem` from my QList model and send it somewhere inside the C++ part of the application?

Comment: did you try to create a mouse area in your MyListItem or override the onClick method?

Comment: @GabrieldeGrimouard I intend the `QList<MyListItem>` element, not `myListItem` as ListView delegate

Comment: You can define a new role (`QAbstractItemModel::roleNames`) which returns that `MyListItem` and use it in the `onClick` event as described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qabstractitemmodel-subclass)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also use `index` property in the delegate to manipulate the data. You just need to transform the QML index into a `QModelIndex` using the index method on your model. Here's a simple example where we change the display value to the string "3" every time a list item gets clicked.

```
ListView {
    id: listView
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: my_model

    delegate: Rectangle {
        height: 50
        width: listView.width

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                // Column is always zero as it's a list
                var column_number = 0; 
                // get `QModelIndex`
                var q_model_index = my_model.index(index, column_number);

                // see for list of roles: 
                // http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#roleNames
                var role = 1

                var data_changed = my_model.setData(q_model_index, "3", role);

                console.log("data change successful?", data_changed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to the `index` property in the delegates, all of the default role names are available in the delegates. So for example, I've used the `decoration` role to set the `color` property of my `Rectangle` delegate before. See [this list](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#roleNames) for more.

```
ListView {
    delegate: Rectangle {
        // list items have access to all default `roleNames` 
        // in addition to the `index` property.
        // For example, using the decoration role, demo'd below
        color: decoration
    }
}
```

Please also see [this link](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68001) where Mitch Curtis recommends using qmlRegisterUncreatableType to register user enums.

Comment: Thanks the property index can solve the issue i can confirm

Answer (score 19):

The comments mention returning a pointer to a `MyListItem` from `data()` to QML and accessing and modifying it in QML.  That requires your `MyListItem` to inherit from `QObject` and adding one `Q_PROPERTY` for each member you want to access in QML. It also requires paying close attention to the object ownership (`QQmlEngine::ObjectOwnership`).

There is another way: Implement `QAbstractListModel::setData()` and `QAbstractListModel::roleNames()`, and the model content can be changed from QML, like `model.roleName = foo`.

Minimal working example below, which doubles the quantity each time the delegate is clicked:

**C++:**

```
struct MyListItem
{
    QString heading;
    QString description;
    int quantity;
};

class MyListModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(MyRoles)
public:
    enum MyRoles {
        HeadingRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        DescriptionRole,
        QuantityRole
    };

    using QAbstractListModel::QAbstractListModel;

    QHash<int,QByteArray> roleNames() const override {
        return { { HeadingRole, "heading" },
            { DescriptionRole, "description" },
            { QuantityRole, "quantity" },
        };
    }
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const override {
        if (parent.isValid())
            return 0;
        return m_list.size();
    }

    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role) override
    {
        if (!hasIndex(index.row(), index.column(), index.parent()) || !value.isValid())
            return false;

        MyListItem &item = m_list[index.row()];
        if (role == DescriptionRole) item.description = value.toString();
        else if (role == HeadingRole) item.heading = value.toString();
        else if (role == QuantityRole) item.quantity = value.toInt();
        else return false;

        emit dataChanged(index, index, { role } );

        return true ;

    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override {
        if (!hasIndex(index.row(), index.column(), index.parent()))
            return {};

        const MyListItem &item = m_list.at(index.row());
        if (role == DescriptionRole) return item.description;
        if (role == HeadingRole) return item.heading;
        if (role == QuantityRole) return item.quantity;

        return {};
    }

private:
    QVector<MyListItem> m_list = {
        { "heading 1", "description 1", 1 },
        { "heading 2", "description 2", 42 },
        { "heading 3", "description 3", 4711 }
    };
};
```

**QML:**

```
ListView {
    id: listView
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: MyListModel {}

    delegate: Item {
        implicitHeight: text.height
        width: listView.width
        Text {
            id: text
            text: model.heading + " " + model.description + " " + model.quantity
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: text
            onClicked: {
                model.quantity *= 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I had so much trouble finding this. Do you know where I can see the documentation for this? I was searching in the QT docs and didn't find it.

Comment: It might be that this isn't documented for QML, at least http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html doesn't mention it, and even incorrectly claims that you need to call setData() explicitly from QML.

Comment: Please just add some qDebug() << "..." to setData() and try to change model.somthing from qml... Seems DelegateModel works with local copy of data, and newer call setData behind of scene... :(

Answer (score 2):

As setRoleNames() is absolute in QAbstractListModel. You can override roleNames() and add your roles explicitly. The simple implementation of inheriting QAbstractListModel is written below.

```
    class BaseListModel : public QAbstractListModel
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_ENUMS(Roles) 
        public:
        enum Roles {
        Name = Qt::UserRole + 1
        };

        virtual QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
        virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
        virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
        virtual bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role) override;
       private:
       QStringList _list;
    };

    // class 
    BaseListModel::BaseListModel(QObject *parent) :
        QAbstractListModel(parent)
    {
        QHash<int, QByteArray> h = RecipeListModel::roleNames();
    }

    QHash<int, QByteArray> BaseListModel::roleNames() const {
        return {
        { Name, "name" },
        };
    }

    int BaseListModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const {
        if (parent.isValid())
        return 0;

        return _list.size();
    }

    QVariant BaseListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
        if (!hasIndex(index.row(), index.column(), index.parent()))
        return {};

        return _list.at(index.row())->data(role);  
    }

    bool RecipeListModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role) {
        if (!hasIndex(index.row(), index.column(), index.parent()) || !value.isValid())
        return false;

        bool ret = _list.at(index.row())->setData(role, value);

        if (ret) {
        emit dataChanged(index, index, { role });
        }

        return ret;
    }

    QVariant BaseListModel::data(int role) const {
        switch(role) {
        case Name:
        return name();
        default:
        return QVariant();
        }
    }

    bool BaseListModel::setData(int role, const QVariant &value)
        switch(role) {
        case Name:
        setName(value.toString());
        return true;
        default:
        return false;
        }
    }
```